# Having HWND handle to given control which is a button how to check it's style/type?

Tags: winapi, button, controls

I mean these styles: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775951(VS.85).aspx

Is `GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE)` the right way ?

Comment: Yes, that's the right way. Also you can get extended styles with `GWL_EXSTYLE`.

Comment: @RogerRowland: post that as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's the right way. Also you can get extended styles with `GWL_EXSTYLE`.